# How do I change the normal page flow for divs?

Tags: css, html

I have the following HTML served by someone else:

```
<div class="surveyTable">
    <div id='fac_light' class='yesno vertical' >
        <div id='fac_light_title' class='title' >Lighting (DT)</div>
        <div id='fac_light_buttons' class='answers' >
            <div id='fac_light_button_0' class='answer' >
                <input id='fac_light_radio_0' type="radio" name="FAC_LIGHT" value="1" checked="yes"/>
            </div>
            <div id='fac_light_button_1' class='answer' >
                <input id='fac_light_radio_1' type="radio" name="FAC_LIGHT" value="2"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='fac_park' class='yesno vertical invalid' >
        <div id='fac_park_title' class='title' >Parking Lot/Curbs (DT)</div>
        <div id='fac_park_buttons' class='answers' >
            <div id='fac_park_button_0' class='answer' >
                <input id='fac_park_radio_0' type="radio" name="FAC_PARK" value="1" checked="yes"/>
            </div>
            <div id='fac_park_button_1' class='answer' >
                <input id='fac_park_radio_1' type="radio" name="FAC_PARK" value="2"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to style the inputs (radio buttons) so they flow left to right on the page and so they line up between the two divs styled by the yesno class.

I don't want to refer to the IDs because that would cause a huge number of classes in my stlyesheet, and anyway, the IDs are machine generated and unreliable.

So far I have the following CSS none of which controls the flow...

```
body
{
    font-family: "trebuchet ms", helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.yesno
{
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

div.invalid
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    border: red 1px dashed;
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

So, you want all divs within the yesno div to be displayed inline?

```
.yesno div { display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float:left;` to the yesno class

Is this what you wanted?

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/hQVHA/

Answer (score 0):

If you use CSS3 (not sure if this works for 2?) you can do it like this :

```
.answers input[type=radio]
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```